# Comunication frontend and backend with aks

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, yaml, azure-aks

application with angular not find another application .net in the same azure-aks

the frontend not find backend and give me a error `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

but when try to call this backend with another backend, works fine

backend yaml's


deployment yaml

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: storageconverter-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: storageconverter-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: storageconverter-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: storageconverter-api 
          image: legacypoc.azurecr.io/storageconverter-api
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: storageconverter-api
spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    selector:
        app: storageconverter-api
```

front end yaml's


deployment yaml

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mainfrontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mainfrontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mainfrontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mainfrontend
          image: legacypoc.azurecr.io/mainfrontend
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: mainfrontend
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - port: 4200
      targetPort: 4200
    selector:
        app: mainfrontend
```

the applications is in the same namespace

the url i'm try to get is

```
http://storageconverter-api.default.svc.cluster.local/api/Menu
```

Comment: Angular runs on the front-end (i.e. in your users' web browser). If you need your front-end to talk to a back-end, you'll need to expose a public ingress point into the cluster that points to your back-end service, and then point your clients to that.

Comment: is there a resource from aks that can make a middle ground between backend and frontend applications?

Comment: You could use an ingress controller. Or your web app could expose an API that it uses that then communicates with your "back-end" API.